# Gradle onlyIf condition for task is not working

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm trying trying to run a gradle task only when an environment Variable is set. I found this `onlyIf` function in https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-run-a-task-only-if-an-environment-variable-is-defined/12438

So I wrote this

```
task onlyRunIfItIsCI() {
    println System.env['CI']
    onlyIf {
        System.env['CI'] == "true"
    }
}
```

However, regardless of if I set the `CI` or not, it still got run. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Are you sure the task is actually run? Please note, that your `println` statement will be executed during configuration phase, regardless of whether the task runs or not. Check out the Gradle output for task results.

Comment: You are right @LukasKörfer. I'm not aware there were configuration stage and saw the printing happens. Now I understood that's just the configuration, where a common operation like print still happens.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently in Gradle, it has 2 pass of execution, first is configuration, and second is execution.

The configuration will be run regardless of the `onlyIf`. To ensure the `onlyIf` is in effect, we should wrap the common execution under the gradle specific scope e.g. `doFirst` or `doLast`

```
task onlyRunIfItIsCI() {
    doFirst {
        println System.env['CI']
    }
    doLast {
        println System.env['CI']
    }
    onlyIf {
        System.env['CI'] == "true"
    }
}

clean.dependsOn onlyRunIfItIsCI
```

Do note, we need to have it `dependsOn`, for the actual execution.

Another example is where the `from` and `into` is gradle specific command where will not run during configuration.

```
task copyPreCommitToGitHook(type: Copy) {
    from new File(rootProject.rootDir, 'storage/pre-commit')
    into { new File(rootProject.rootDir, '.git/hooks') }
    onlyIf {
        System.env['CI'] == null
    }
}

tasks.getByPath(':app:preBuild').dependsOn copyPreCommitToGitHook
```